# What features distinguish the hymnic-epic style from Standard Babylonian?

Tags: style, akkadian-language

In the general introduction to *Before the Muses: An Anthology of Akkadian Literature* (third edition, CDL Press, 2005)
Benjamin R. Foster discusses the "Akkadian literary languages":

> The Babylonians believed that literature required a special idiom,
>   using grammar, vocabulary, syntax, sound, and even spelling removed from
>   common usage. The most refined literary style of this period is known as
>   the "hymnic-epic dialect". (...)
>   In the Mature and Late periods of Akkadian literature, (...),
>   another literary style known as "Standard Babylonian" was used.

However, Foster's introduction does not give examples that clarify
how the hymnic-epic style and Standard Babylonian differed from each other.
What exactly were the differences from the point of view of grammar,
vocabulary, syntax and sound?